# Question on linear algebra (sets and vector subspaces)

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: Homework]

A and B are not subspaces because they are not closed under vector addition. Am i right? What about the basis and dimension?

Comment: Why do you think $\mathcal{B}$ is not closed under addition? To demonstrate this, you would have to find two vectors in $\mathcal{B}$ with sum not in $\mathcal{B}$, and I think this will be challenging...

Comment: What did you try to compute the basis?

Answer (score 2):

$A$ is not closed under vector addition, and neither is $D$.  $B,C$ are vector spaces.

$B$ has basis $\{(4,2,1)\}$.    $C$ has basis $$\left\{\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1&0\\-1&0&0\\0&0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right),\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\-1&0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right),\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&-1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)\right\}$$